# How do I set a DateTimePicker to default value with my reset Button?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

This is my reset Button:

```
private void resetuj()
{
      tbID.Clear();
      tbIme.Clear();
      tbPrezime.Clear();
      cbUcesnik.SelectedIndex = -1;
      cbProgrami.SelectedIndex = -1;
      dateTimePicker1.Value.
}
```

Comment: `dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;` ?

Comment: Or `dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.MinValue`?

Comment: @Charlieface You should test it :)

Comment: @Jimi what do you mean?

Comment: @Charlieface What is the `MinDate` of a DateTimePicker?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set `dateTimePicker1` value, you need to change "2020/12/03" and here write your date.

```
‍‍dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Parse("2020/12/03");
```

if you want to `dateTimePicker1 default` value, then

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
```